# Why does Meta Stack Exchange have a separate reputation system while the other meta sites do not?

Tags: discussion, reputation, meta, up-votes

I know that meta sites are meant to be a place for discussion and feature requests. Which is why the meta sites do not have a separate reputation system and anything on the meta site will not affect the reputation on the main site.

However, Meta Stack Exchange is different. It has a separate reputation system, but it is a meta site! I heard someone says that votes on meta sites have different meanings from the ones on the main sites. The votes on meta sites mean agreement to the OP's idea. So I guess it's more opinion-based. Because of this, votes do not affect your reputation on the main site.

So I just want to ask, if the posts and votes are opinion based and are mainly just discussions, why does Meta Stack Exchange have a reputation system?

Comment: *"The votes on meta sites mean agreement to the OP's idea"* .. not exclusively. The regular meaning of votes still exists as well. And Meta SE does not have a main site. It's a meta of the entire network. As such reputation is an appropriate concept here, leading to the same effects and privileges as they would on a regular main site.

Comment: Don't let the initial context of the duplicate confuse you. "Meta Stack Overflow" used to be what "Meta Stack Exchange" is now. The global-network-meta. So the answers there relate to your question as well.