# Why is Meta Stack Exchange classified as “main site” and not “meta site?”

Tags: feature-request, meta, mobile-app

On my Stack Exchange iOS app, this Meta Stack Exchange site cannot be found when I filter by *meta sites*. Rather, it is considered one of the *main sites*.

**Why is this? Could it be changed?**

This unexpected classification made it harder for me to locate the site. But, alas, I finally did. :-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does Meta Stack Exchange have a separate reputation system while the other meta sites do not?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/268276/why-does-meta-stack-exchange-have-a-separate-reputation-system-while-the-other-m)

Comment: @gnat My question has nothing to do with reputation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MSE is... special. It *works* like a normal site, with its own reputation system and all that, since the concept of the [per site meta](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/07/22/new-per-site-metas/) came after it. It works *exactly* like a meta-less main site (like all sites were in the early days). Meta was apparently [supposed to be different in many ways](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/06/28/cmon-get-meta/), but that special casing didn't happen.

It was even *MSO* for a while cause a meta for Stack Exchange doesn't exist. It doesn't even have a proper SE QA site as a parent since SE.com's kind of the landing page for the network.

Changing it would probably mean special casing it to be a meta site without a parent site with reputation. Which it mostly is, other than its a special case of a main site acting as a meta without a meta site. Once again, the history is strange, and Meta was kind of one of those things that's evolved over time, like a self-aware fungus.

I suppose that it's possible they could special case it in the apps (but [app development's pretty much maintenance only at this point of time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/299862/are-more-mobile-app-review-or-moderation-features-coming))

Comment: "app development's pretty much maintenance only at this point of time" Why? Does noone work on that? Why not?

Comment: See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/299862/are-more-mobile-app-review-or-moderation-features-coming